# Simplest way to collect data from python code running on separate computers but on same network

Tags: python, concurrency

making a simple rssi map that collects data from different computers running on the same network, what is the easiest way to collect the data

Comment: The easiest way to implement that would be to have an intern run back and forth and write everything down. I doubt that's what you want though so perhaps you could elaborate some more and show us some code?

Comment: sorry, im just looking for a method of congregating some values(strings.integers) to one computer

Comment: That could mean any number of things depending on how your system is working. How much data? How fast is it coming? Do you have a database you can use? Can you write to file? What format is it in? Any answer someone writes for you could become immediately invalidated by the answer to one of those questions so it's important for you to explain your question as much as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it succinctly - use a database. A database can be set up and interfaced with via http fairly trivially. Python has a lot of great library support in that area.

I can't tell you what database to use because I am not sure what your data looks like, or what you plan on doing with it. If you need to store a lot of stuff fast possibly for later more robust processing I'd suggest some sort of nosql solution, for relational data possibly PostgreSQL. You'll need to do some investigation on your own about what might work for you and your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use either database (MongoDB, Postgres, etc.) or messaging (For example http://zeromq.org/ )

Or just write files to a common network storage.